# Setting up Play Framework 2.3.x with Java 7 support

Tags: java, playframework

I want to setup a Play Framework application which runs on Java 7. The latest versions of Play Framework does not support Java 7. So by looking at the [change log](https://www.playframework.com/changelog) I figured out [2.3.10](https://www.playframework.com/download#older-versions) is the one I want.

Weirdly though, the activator links for every 2.3.x+ version points to the same place. Also downloading and running them would set up Play Framework 2.4.3 without any kind of questions asked.

Below is the my terminal output:

```
shyam@shyam-work:~/Applications/activator-1.3.6-minimal$ cd
shyam@shyam-work:~$ cd Applications
shyam@shyam-work:~/Applications$ cd activator-1.3.6-minimal/
shyam@shyam-work:~/Applications/activator-1.3.6-minimal$ ./activator new

Fetching the latest list of templates...

Browse the list of templates: http://typesafe.com/activator/templates
Choose from these featured templates or enter a template name:
  1) minimal-akka-java-seed
  2) minimal-akka-scala-seed
  3) minimal-java
  4) minimal-scala
  5) play-java
  6) play-scala
(hit tab to see a list of all templates)
> 5
Enter a name for your application (just press enter for 'play-java')
> play-java
OK, application "play-java" is being created using the "play-java" template.

To run "play-java" from the command line, "cd play-java" then:
/home/shyam/Applications/activator-1.3.6-minimal/play-java/activator run

To run the test for "play-java" from the command line, "cd play-java" then:
/home/shyam/Applications/activator-1.3.6-minimal/play-java/activator test

To run the Activator UI for "play-java" from the command line, "cd play-java" then:
/home/shyam/Applications/activator-1.3.6-minimal/plpay-java/activator ui

shyam@shyam-work:~/Applications/activator-1.3.6-minimal$ cd play-java/
shyam@shyam-work:~/Applications/activator-1.3.6-minimal/play-java$ cd project/
shyam@shyam-work:~/Applications/activator-1.3.6-minimal/play-java/project$ ls
build.properties  plugins.sbt
shyam@shyam-work:~/Applications/activator-1.3.6-minimal/play-java/project$ nano plugins.sbt

  GNU nano 2.2.6          File: plugins.sbt                            

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.3")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for pu$
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. $
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per $
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

// Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in y$
// enablePlugins(SbtEbean). Note, uncommenting this line will automati$
// Play enhancer, regardless of whether the line above is commented ou$
// addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

As you can see, the plugins.sbt file says 2.4.3 and build fails on Java 7.

Now, I have tried this by downloading 2.3.10 as well as 2.3.9 versions link. In both case the same results were produced.

Consequently, I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069320/unsupportedclassversionerror-on-running-play-application-with-jdk-1-7#comment50158358_31069457) but that gave rise to a different build fail error altogether.

```
/home/shyam/Applications/activator-1.3.6-minimal/play-java/build.sbt:17: error: not found: value routesGenerator
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
^
[error] Type error in expression
```

I tried fixing this with another SO post(unfortunately I tried it some time ago and at this point I don't have the patience to go through all this again) which too gave an entirely new error.

So my question is: How hard is it to actually setup a simple Play Framework application to run on Java 7?

Comment: You can try one of the 2.2.x versions. They don't use this Activator.

Comment: Yes. That might work. I would really like to know why this doesn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

Activator does not determine the version of play as far as I understand. It uses the information in files such as `plugins.sbt` to determine which version of play will be used for that particular app. That is why the different version  links point to the same activator.

`plugins.sbt` comes with the template (seed app) you are downloading, so you will either need a 2.3.x template (try downloading one manually from the [activator templates page](https://www.typesafe.com/activator/templates) for example), or you will need to "reverse migrate" the 2.4 app that you have downloaded (probably quite a time consuming exercise, as there are some important changes between the versions).