# UnsupportedClassVersionError on play with JDK 1.7

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator

I am getting the same error as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069320/unsupportedclassversionerror-on-running-play-application-with-jdk-1-7) post. i'm trying to resolve the problem as mentioned in the proposed solution but i didn't understand how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using version 2.4.x (or newer), you must use Java 8. From the [Highlights of version 2.4](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Highlights24#Java-8-support):

> Play 2.4 now requires JDK 8. Due to this, Play can, out of the box, provide support for Java 8 data types. For example, Play’s JSON APIs now support Java 8 temporal types including Instance, LocalDateTime and LocalDate.

To confirm that you are using Play 2.4, see file `project/plugins.sbt`.

#### Edit:

If you can't (or don't want to) use Java 8, you have to use Play 2.3 instead. To do so, you must edit `project/plugins.sbt` to change the used version of Play:

```
// Notice we are now using version 2.3.10
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.10")
```

If this is a brand new project, you can recreate it using 2.3 template instead:

```
 activator new play-scala-2.3 name-of-your-project
```

Or, for Java:

```
activator new play-java-2.3 name-of-your-project
```

Comment: Thanks what if I would like to use java 8?

Comment: Just do it. :-) As I said, play 2.4 targets java 8.

Comment: sorry I mean what if i would like to use java 7 ? it is clear and simple with 8 version